# Posted saved item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This method is giving a problem on my website. Every time I try to unselected all items in my list and leave the page and return to the page it is still selected. I don't know what is going on. Can some one help me with this? Sorry didn't know how to format it at first but here is the rest of it.

Model

```
public class CBItem
    {
        //Integer value of a checkbox
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //String name of a checkbox
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //Boolean value to select a checkbox
        //on the list
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        //Object of html tags to be applied
        //to checkbox, e.g.:'new{tagName = "tagValue"}'
        public htmlTag Tags { get; set; }

    }

    public class SettingsParam
            {
                public SettingsParam()
                {
                }
                public LocalPasswordModel passModel { get; set; } 
                public CBListViewModel savedCharts { get; set; }
                public CBListViewModel savedSpreads { get; set; }
                public CBListViewModel savedYrSels { get; set; }
            }   

Controller




// POST: /Account/Manage
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Settings(SettingsParam model, string submitBtn)
                {
                    resetCBLists(model);
                    ViewBag.Message = "";

                    if (submitBtn.Equals("Save Email Selection"))
                    {
                        DavidChart.Models.UsersSChartContext chartCon = new DavidChart.Models.UsersSChartContext();
                        System.Linq.IQueryable<DavidChart.Models.UserSaveChart> userCharts = chartCon.UsersSCharts.Where<DavidChart.Models.UserSaveChart>(p => (p.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId));
                        CBItem selItem;

                        foreach (var item in userCharts)
                        {
                            if (model.savedCharts.SelectedItems == null)
                            {
                                selItem = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selItem = model.savedCharts.SelectedItems.FirstOrDefault<CBItem>(i => (i.Id == item.ChartId));
                            }

                            if (selItem != null)
                            {
                                item.SendEmail = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                item.SendEmail = false;
                            }
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            int i = chartCon.SaveChanges();
                            ViewBag.Message += "Email Selection Saved";
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                        }
                    }
                     else if (submitBtn.Equals("Delete Custom Spread"))
                {
                    MemoryStream stream;
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                    DavidChart.Models.UserSettingsContext userSetCon = new DavidChart.Models.UserSettingsContext();
                    DavidChart.Models.UserSettings dbEntity = userSetCon.UserSets.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId));

                    if (dbEntity != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbEntity.SaveSpreads))
                    {
                        byte[] fromDB = Convert.FromBase64String(dbEntity.SaveSpreads);
                        stream = new MemoryStream(fromDB);
                        Models.SaveSpreads SaveS = (DavidChart.Models.SaveSpreads)bf.Deserialize(stream);

                        var list = new List<ValueTextPair>(SaveS.SpreadTypes);

                        foreach (var item in model.savedSpreads.SelectedItems)
                        {
                            var sel = list.First<ValueTextPair>(i => (i.Text.Equals(item.Name)));
                            list.Remove(sel);
                        }
                        SaveS.SpreadTypes = list.ToArray();

                        stream = new MemoryStream();
                        bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                        bf.Serialize(stream, SaveS);
                        byte[] bArry = stream.ToArray();
                        string toDBstr = Convert.ToBase64String(bArry);
                        dbEntity.SaveSpreads = toDBstr;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int i = userSetCon.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Message += "Custom Spread Deleted";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                    }
                }
                else if (submitBtn.Equals("Delete Year Selection"))
                {
                    MemoryStream stream;
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                    DavidChart.Models.UserSettingsContext userSetCon = new DavidChart.Models.UserSettingsContext();
                    DavidChart.Models.UserSettings dbEntity = userSetCon.UserSets.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId));

                    if (dbEntity != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbEntity.SaveYears))
                    {
                        byte[] fromDB = Convert.FromBase64String(dbEntity.SaveYears);
                        stream = new MemoryStream(fromDB);
                        Models.SaveYears SaveY = (DavidChart.Models.SaveYears)bf.Deserialize(stream);

                        var list = new List<ValueTextPair>(SaveY.YearSel);

                        foreach (var item in model.savedYrSels.SelectedItems)
                        {
                            var sel = list.First<ValueTextPair>(i => (i.Text.Equals(item.Name)));
                            list.Remove(sel);
                        }
                        SaveY.YearSel = list.ToArray();

                        stream = new MemoryStream();
                        bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                        bf.Serialize(stream, SaveY);
                        byte[] bArry = stream.ToArray();
                        string toDBstr = Convert.ToBase64String(bArry);
                        dbEntity.SaveYears = toDBstr;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int i = userSetCon.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Message += "Year Selection Deleted";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                    ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
                    if (hasLocalAccount)
                    {
                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                            bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                            try
                            {
                                changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.passModel.OldPassword, model.passModel.NewPassword);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                            }

                            if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Settings", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
                        // OldPassword field
                        ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                        if (state != null)
                        {
                            state.Errors.Clear();
                        }

                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.passModel.NewPassword);
                                return RedirectToAction("Settings", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Unable to create local account. An account with the name \"{0}\" may already exist.", User.Identity.Name));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                resetCBLists(model);

                return View(model);
            }
            private DavidChart.Models.ViewModels.CBListViewModel GetListViewModel(DavidChart.Models.ViewModels.PostedItems postedItems, IEnumerable<CBItem> itemList)
            {
                // setup properties
                var model = new DavidChart.Models.ViewModels.CBListViewModel();
                var selectedItems = new List<CBItem>();
                var postedIds = new string[0];
                if (postedItems == null) 
                    postedItems = new PostedItems();

                // if a view model array of posted ids exists
                // and is not empty,save selected ids
                if (postedItems.CBItemIds != null && postedItems.CBItemIds.Any())
                {
                    postedIds = postedItems.CBItemIds;
                }

                // if there are any selected ids saved, create a list of CBItems
                if (postedIds.Any())
                {
                    selectedItems = itemList
                     .Where(x => postedIds.Any(s => x.Id.ToString().Equals(s)))
                     .ToList();
                }

                //setup a view model
                model.AvailableItems = itemList.ToList();
                model.SelectedItems = selectedItems;
                model.PostedItems = postedItems;
                return model;
            }
            private void resetCBLists(SettingsParam model) 
            {
                var chartL = chartList();
                var spreadL = spreadList();
                var yrselL = yrselList();
                if (model.savedCharts == null)
                {
                    var cblist = new CBListViewModel();
                    var selectedItems = new List<CBItem>();
                    cblist.AvailableItems = chartList();
                    cblist.SelectedItems = chartSel();
                    model.savedCharts = cblist;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.savedCharts = GetListViewModel(model.savedCharts.PostedItems, chartL);
                }
                if (model.savedSpreads == null)
                {
                    var cblist = new CBListViewModel();
                    var selectedItems = new List<CBItem>();
                    cblist.AvailableItems = spreadList();
                    cblist.SelectedItems = selectedItems;
                    model.savedSpreads = cblist;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.savedSpreads = GetListViewModel(model.savedSpreads.PostedItems, spreadL);
                }
                if (model.savedYrSels == null)
                {
                    var cblist = new CBListViewModel();
                    var selectedItems = new List<CBItem>();
                    cblist.AvailableItems = yrselList();
                    cblist.SelectedItems = selectedItems;
                    model.savedYrSels = cblist;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.savedYrSels = GetListViewModel(model.savedYrSels.PostedItems, yrselL);
                }
            }
```

View

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.savedSpreads.PostedItems.CBItemIds,
                                  model => model.savedSpreads.AvailableItems,
                                  item => item.Id,
                                  item => item.Name,
                                  model => model.savedSpreads.SelectedItems,
                                  MvcCheckBoxList.Model.Position.Vertical)
```

Comment: You'll need to add the code that populates the View

Comment: Sorry here is the rest of it.

Comment: No body will wade through all this awful code. I suspect your posting back a value of either true or false then changing the model value to the opposite then expecting that value to be reflected in the view when you return it. If that the case you need to clear `ModelState` for the property before changing its value (the `ModelState` value takes precedence over the model value if your using html helpers).